# Regular expression to replace a value in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to replace all `example.com` instances with `<a href="http://example.com">example.com</a>` in a string:

```
content.gsub(/example\.com/, '<a href="http://example.com">example.com</a>')
```

But I don't want to replace `example.com` if there's a dot before it, like in `www.example.com`. So my first thought is to make the regular expression `/[^\.]example.com/`. But then, of course, `gsub!` will replace the character before `example.com` too.

Is there an easy way to replace all the `example.com`s that don't have a `.` in front, in Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this with a negative lookbehind:

```ruby
content.gsub(/((?<!\.)example.com)/i , '<a href="http://\1">\1</a>')
```

The part that says `(?<!\.)` literally means "if not preceded by a `.`".

A negative look-behind is a zero-width assertion, so it is not part of the match, and therefore won't be replaced.

**Note that these are only supported in Ruby 1.9+**

This example also captures the domain itself so that it can be used in the replace, which makes it easy to swap it out with a variable, and I made it case insensitive (by ending the expression with `/i`) just because it made more sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `back reference` in `gsub`:

```
content.gsub(/(^|[^.])example\.com/, '\\1<a href="http://example.com">example.com</a>')
```

`(^|[^.])` will match start of input or non dot character.